# parameter estimation using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, parameters

I am trying to create a nueral network using tensor flow. I am not using keras api. I have some parameter estimation(weight,bias and some other parameters) to do. The code is working but the parameter estimation is really bad  and error percentage is very high what is the problem here? I tried so many ways still no improvement. the loss fn is less.

I tried creating my own optimizer but the process is slow and the error is large. Is there any way to apply optimizers parameter.

```
import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import scipy.io
    from scipy.interpolate import griddata
    from pyDOE import lhs
    import math as ma



class PhysicsInformedNN:
    def __init__(self,X_n,v,layers,lb,ub):
        self.lb = lb
        self.ub = ub
        self.layers = layers
        
        self.dx_n = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_n[:,0:1],dtype = 'float32')
        self.t_n = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_n[:,1:2],dtype = 'float32')
        self.v_r = tf.convert_to_tensor(v,dtype = 'float32')

        
        self.lambda_1 = tf.Variable(0,dtype = 'float32')#1.5
        self.lambda_2 = tf.Variable(-6,dtype = 'float32')


        self.para =[self.lambda_1,self.lambda_2]
        
        self.weights, self.biases = self.initialize_NN(layers)
        
        
        
    def initialize_NN(self,layers):
        weights = []
        biases = []
        num_layers = len(layers) 
        for l in range(0,num_layers-1):
            W = self.xavier_init(size=[layers[l], layers[l+1]])
            b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,layers[l+1]], dtype='float32'), dtype='float32')
            weights.append(W)
            biases.append(b)        
        return weights, biases
    
    def xavier_init(self, size):
        in_dim = size[0]
        out_dim = size[1]        
        xavier_stddev = np.sqrt(2/(in_dim + out_dim))
        return tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([in_dim, out_dim], stddev=xavier_stddev), dtype='float32')
    
    def neural_net(self, X, weights, biases):
        num_layers = len(weights) + 1
        
        H = 2.0*(X - self.lb)/(self.ub - self.lb) - 1.0
        for l in range(0,num_layers-2):
            W = weights[l]
            b = biases[l]
            H = tf.math.tanh(tf.math.add(tf.linalg.matmul(H, W), b))
        W = weights[-1]
        b = biases[-1]
        Y = tf.math.add(tf.linalg.matmul(H, W), b)
        return Y
    
    def net_u(self, x, t):
        v = self.neural_net(tf.concat([x,t],1), self.weights, self.biases)
        return v
    


    
    def net_f(self, x, t):
        lambda_1 = self.para[0]       
        lambda_2 = tf.exp(self.para[1])
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape :
                tape.watch(t)
                tape.watch(x)
                u = self.net_u(x,t)
                u_x = tape.gradient(u,x)
        u_t = tape.gradient(u,t)
        
        u_xx = tape.gradient(u_x,x)
        
        f = u_t + lambda_1*u*u_x - lambda_2*u_xx
        del tape
        return f
    
    
    def callback(self, loss,n):
        print('Loss:', loss, ' Epoch : ', n)
        
    def train(self,epoch):
        
        for i in range(epoch):
            
            with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape :
                tape.watch(self.weights)
                tape.watch(self.biases)
                tape.watch(self.para)
                f_pred = self.net_f(self.dx_n, self.t_n)
                v_pred = self.net_u(self.dx_n, self.t_n)
                loss =  tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.v_r - v_pred)) + tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(f_pred))
            dw = tape.gradient(loss,self.weights)
            db = tape.gradient(loss,self.biases)
            dp = tape.gradient(loss,self.para)
            lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
                                                initial_learning_rate=1e-2,
                                                                    decay_steps=10000,
                                                                            decay_rate=0.9)
            optimizer1 = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
            optimizer1.apply_gradients(zip(dw, self.weights))
            optimizer1.apply_gradients(zip(db, self.biases))
            optimizer2 = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
            optimizer2.apply_gradients(zip(dp, self.para))
            del tape
            self.callback(loss,i)
            
    def predict(self, X_star):
                
        v_star = self.net_u(X_star[:,0:1], X_star[:,1:2])
        f_star = f_pred = self.net_f(X_star[:,0:1], X_star[:,1:2])
        para_last = self.para
        return v_star, f_star, para_last
 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #PARAMETERS for the problem
    
    np.random.seed(123)
    nu =0.01/np.pi
    
    layers = [2, 20, 20, 20, 20, 1]
    N_u = 2000
        
    data = scipy.io.loadmat('burgers_shock.mat')
    
    t = data['t'].flatten()[:,None]
    x = data['x'].flatten()[:,None]
    Exact = np.real(data['usol']).T
    X, T = np.meshgrid(x,t)
    X_star = np.hstack((X.flatten()[:,None], T.flatten()[:,None]))
    u_star = Exact.flatten()[:,None]
    lb = X_star.min(0)
    ub = X_star.max(0)
    idx = np.random.choice(X_star.shape[0], N_u, replace=False)
    X_u_train = X_star[idx,:]
    u_train = u_star[idx,:]
    
    model = PhysicsInformedNN(X_u_train, u_train, layers, lb, ub)
    model.train(1000)


X_star = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_star,dtype='float32')
u_pred, f_pred, param = model.predict(X_star)

error_lambda_1 = np.abs(param[0] - 1.0)*100
error_lambda_2 = np.abs( np.exp(param[1])- nu)/nu * 100


print(error_lambda_1,error_lambda_2)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please post your code to reproduce your problem.